# How to hide part of cell content?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide part of the cell content in Excel like in MS Word where we can set the [Hidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.hidden) property of a selected text. The idea is to display a representative part while the underlying data can be retrieved by `Range(...).Value2`. Unfortunately, I don't see the `Hidden` property in Excel's [Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Font(object)) object.

As an alternative, I thought some [custom number format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5) could be used. I found the content placeholder `@`, so I can hide, replace and pad text. However, I don't see an option to display content partially.

**Is it possible to set the displayed part of the text in cells?**

[image]

---

#### update Jun 26, 2022

At the moment I'm using a combination of event handling and number formatting. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const Data = "A1"    ' data area to look for
Dim Common As Range
Dim Cell As Range
    Set Common = Intersect(Target, Range(Data))
    If Common Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each Cell In Common
        Cell.NumberFormat = GetFormat(Cell.Value2)
    Next Cell
End Sub
 
Private Function GetFormat(ByVal Value) As String
' Return the first five characters for demonstration purposes
Const Quote = """"
Dim Output as String
    Output = Left(Value, 5) & "..."
    GetFormat = ";;;" & Quote & Output & Quote
End Function
```

with this result:

[image]

As before, I hope this process can be simplified.

Comment: Format some text the background color of the cell.

Comment: No matter what you to do to hide text in ab Excel cell, you're always going to be able to see actual text in the content formula bar just by clicking in the cell

Comment: Use "SUBSTITUTE" to include/exclude the desired text when necessary

Comment: You may also want to consider that each cell can contain comments, which are hidden and could use for anything you want... https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/add-or-remove-cell-comments/

Comment: @dbmitch That is the point. I want to apply to the text the same approach as to the date or number formatting. Just as an example, if the text is the full path to the file, I'd like to see the file name only, but the underlying value should be the full path (it's not my goal, only illustration). Another example - hide the full message and keep only mentioned names. Or hide the full message and show only its pattern.

Comment: @SolarMike Not exactly what I'm looking for. With number formatting I get not only clear view but additional opportunities to filter data.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your answer, there is no `hidden` Font property in Excel as one can find in Word. However, there are a variety of workarounds that would give the same functionality of "sort of hidden" (note that this is not a security feature). The use case for this in Word seems (to me) somewhat minimal except maybe to change the way something is printed and keeping notes? [Comments and Notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-comments-and-notes-in-excel-bdcc9f5d-38e2-45b4-9a92-0b2b5c7bf6f8#:%7E:text=Insert%20simple%20notes%20for%20annotation,Click%20outside%20the%20cell.) in a cell would probably be more appropriate.

I was first thinking of using a font color, but that is functionally different than the Hide property because the Hide property removes the text rather than whites it out (so you would have a blank space the length of the hidden text).

Overall, I think that using an `if statement` within a string of your text with a global `true/false` driving cell would probably be the closest thing.

For example if cell `A1` had either true or false, then any cell with the below formula could toggle between showing and not showing the hidden text:

```
="I have "&IF(A1,"a hidden text  ","")& "to think about."
```

If you *never* wanted the text to be visible, then you could just hard code it `false`.

```
="I have "&IF(False,"a hidden text  ","")& "to think about."
```

While not directly related to your question, if you were looking to have some *notes* within a cell formula that was a value (not text), the [N function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9) has been something I've used as it converts any text to zero, so it can be included after a calculation. Example:

```
=SUM(A:A)+N("This is a summation of all values in column A")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `N("some note")` hack.

Comment: @Vitalizzare, you're welcome. As a friendly reminder (i.e. pathetic begging attempt by me), StackOverflow functions on `Accepted` answers. Thanks.